# The set $D_h$ of points at which $h:S \to S'$ is not continuous is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Below is a statement from Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures. Assume that $h:\mathscr{S} \to \mathscr{S}'$ is a function from a metric space to another metric space. In the proof below, I cannot show that $A_{\epsilon \delta}$ is open. How can we find, for any $x \in A_{\epsilon \delta}$, ball $B(x,d)$ contained in it?

[image]

Comment: Does this perhaps follow from the metric being a continuous function?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in A_{\epsilon \delta}$ and $y, z \in S$ satisfying $\rho(x, y) < \delta$, $\rho(x, z) < \delta$ and $\rho'(hy, hz) \geq \epsilon$

Consider $w \in B_{\frac{\delta}{2}}$:

$$
\rho(w, y) < \delta \\
\rho(w, z) < \delta \\
\rho'(hy, hz) \geq \epsilon
$$

Hence $w \in A_{\epsilon \delta} \implies A_{\epsilon \delta}$ is open.